# Unable to open mxd file on my computer - can be opened on other computers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mxd, serious-application-error

Using ArcGIS Arcmap 10.5.1.

Several of the mxd files I have created and worked on are no longer accessible to me. If I attempt to open these files, the loading screen progresses through "Initializing license / initializing application / loading document" and stops on loading document. I then get the following error screen:

[image]

I've sent the error report a few times now, but have not received a response.

I restarted the arcgis program by following these steps: https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile 
That fixed a different problem I was having, but not the locked mxd files.

The files are not corrupt - my coworkers can open them on their computers.

Comment: Try a few more of the steps listed on this thread: starting ArcMap with logging on and/or repairing the ArcGIS application in Windows. https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-7545

Comment: Also, please confirm that ArcMap opens in general (i.e. Start ArcMap, try to open the problem map. If crash, start ArcMap, create new map, save & close, then reopen and try to open the blank map.)

Comment: make your mxd read-only (will force save as) >> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23416/making-map-document-mxd-locked-uneditable

Answer (score 3):

I have a problem with this sort of crashing when opening an MXD, turns out it is the version of Access I have installed (2016), it keeps running an install process when I open Access which is corrupting ArcMap. ArcMap crashes if the MXD is linking to any modern Excel documents (XLSX).

As it is a University machine I have no control of what gets installed/updates and the work around is to run the microsoft update *everytime* I have opened and closed Access... very tedious...

As your problem is specific to ArcMap you should be posting on GeoNet for example there is a discussion there about [After Windows 10 upgrade attempting to use an Excel .xlsx file crashes ArcMap](https://community.esri.com/message/719962-re-after-windows-10-upgrade-attempting-to-use-an-excel-xlsx-file-crashes-arcmap?commentID=719962).